# no matching function for call to 'getline'

Tags: c++, getline, istream

I have a class called `parser`:

```
class parser {
  const std::istream& stream;
public:
  parser(const std::istream& stream_) : stream(stream_) {}
  ~parser() {}

  void parse();
};
```

In `parser::parse` I want to loop over each line, so I use `std::getline`:

```
std::getline(stream, line)
```

The compiler gives me this error, however:

> ```
> src/parser.cc:10:7: error: no matching function for call to 'getline'
>     std::getline(stream, line);
>     ^~~~~~~~~~~~
> ```

But the first argument to `std::getline` is of type `std::istream&`, right? What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first argument to `getline` is of type `istream&`, *not* `istream const &`. (Reading from a stream changes its state.) Take the `const` qualifier off your `parser::stream` member.